# "git pull" does not update my local repository

Tags: git

I have a local repository on my computer and a remote one on my server.

Whenever I change something on my computer, I commit the changes to my remote repository (which I created by doing "git init --bare" and adding a post-receive hook).

I made some changes directly on the remote server and I would like to update my local repository so that is has the same files, but whenever I do "git pull", it won't update my local repository.

I feel like it has something with git hooks but I'm no expert.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A few questions: What post-receive hooks do you have in the remote repo? You write you make changes on the remote server. How? Did you commit these changes to the git repo (how?).

Comment: Here is my post-receive hook : `export GIT_WORK_TREE=/PATH_TO_MY_WORKING_DIRECTORY
git checkout -f`. I just edited file directory on the remote repository by using vim, I did not use Git.

Comment: what message do you get when you run git pull? are you sure you have commited changes you've made on your remote?

Comment: @west you edited your remote repository file with vim but it is still in a git repository so you would have to commit that change. You updated a file likely in your master branch on the remote repository but if you didn't commit it your git pull won't actually pull down that change.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems you made changes to the working directory of your remote repository, but never committed them. These changes can not be fetched using `git pull`.

Pushing/pulling can only transfer commits, so you must commit your changes first.